# Наезжают слова друг на друга CSS

Tags: html, css

Получается при сужении экрана "Битрикс" съезжает на "Купите лицензию". Подскажите как можно поправить

https://jsfiddle.net/uz28muad/

```
    .newbackg {
  background: #000000 url("../images/background.png") no-repeat;
  max-width: 1170px;
  height: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  }





.newbackg h2 {
  font-family: Myriad Pro;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ff3366;
  position: absolute;
  top: -35px;
  left: 100px;

}
 .newbackg h3 {
    font-family: Myriad Pro;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 100px;

   }

   .newbackg h4 {
    font-family: Myriad Pro;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 125px;
    left: 100px;

   }
  .newbackgtr {
    position: absolute;
    right: 80px;
    bottom: 35px;
  }



.butt {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 80px;
```

Comment: а все заголовки через position:absolute; не лутше отступами (margin, padding) сделать ? тогда возможно проблема решиться ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все разобрался.

```
    <div class="newbackg-info">
       <div class="newbackg-info_sale"> Скидка на хостинг при покупке лицензии CMS 1С-Битрикс</div>
        <div class="newbackg-info_license">Купите лицензию 1С-Битрикс и получите
             от 25% до 100% скидку на хостинг(на 1 год)</div>
    </div>

    .newbackg .newbackg-info {
position: absolute;
top: 90px;
left: 100px;
  }

 .newbackg .newbackg-info_sale {
    font-family: Myriad Pro;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: relative;

   }

   .newbackg .newbackg-info_license {
    font-family: Myriad Pro;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: relative;


   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.newbackg {
  background: #000000 url("../images/background.png") no-repeat;
  max-width: 1170px;
  height: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  }
  
  
 

    
.newbackg h2 {
  font-family: Myriad Pro;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ff3366;
  position: absolute;
  top: -35px;
  left: 100px;

}
 .newbackg h3 {
    font-family: Myriad Pro;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 100px;

   }
  
   .newbackg h4 {
    font-family: Myriad Pro;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 190px;
    left: 100px;
  
   }
  .newbackgtr {
    position: absolute;
    right: 80px;
    bottom: 35px;
  }



.butt {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 80px;
```

```html
      <div class="newbackg">
      

        <h2>Акция:</h2>
        <h3>Скидка на хостинг при покупке лицензии CMS 1С-Битрикс</h3>
        <h4>Купите лицензию 1С-Битрикс и получите от 25% до 100% скидку на хостинг(на 1 год)</h4>
        <div class="newbackgtr"> <img src="images/1c-bitrix.png" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="butt"><a class="shop-button" href="#">Подробнее о тарифах на хостинг</a></div>
    </div>
```